# Use Transactions for Synchronization in Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

We have a method that has reads and writes to MySql, the method can be called by multiple threads. The db operations are like:

```
public List<Record> getAndUpdate() {
    Task task = taskMapper.selectByPrimaryKey(id);
    if (task.getStatus() == 0) {
        insertRecords();
        task.setStatus(1);
        taskMapper.update(task);
    } 

    // some queries and return data
    return someRecordMapper.selectByXXX();
}

private void insertRecords() {
    // read some files and create someRecords
    someRecordMapper.insertBatch(someRecords);
}
```

The method reads a task's status, if the status is 0, it then inserts a bunch of records (of that task) to the `Records` table, and then set the status of the task to 1.

I want those DB operations to be transactional and exclusive, meaning that when one thread enters the transaction, other threads trying to read the same
task should block. Otherwise, they will see task status as 0 and `insertRecords()` will be called multiple times, resulting in duplicated data.

The `@Transactional` annotation doesn't seem to block transactions from other threads, it only ensures rollback in case of abortion. So I think with `@Transactional` alone, the above issue cannot be avoided.

I'm using MySql with mybatis, I think MySql itself can achieve such synchronization between threads so I try not to introduce extra components such as redis lock to do it. I wonder how can I do it in Spring?

Comment: have you tried to use synchronized blocks?

Comment: @JoseLuis It's a distributed system, the lock needs to be in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

Ｉ ended up using the `"SELECT ... FOR UPDATE"` query. With this query executed, all the other reads/writes are locked until the current transaction commits or gets rolled back. Also need to annotate the method with `@Transactional`. But the row lock and the transaction here are 2 different concerns. The test results is satisfactory.